# How to integrate native facebook in ios (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with Auth0 Facebook login. I want that when the user clicks the Facebook button in my app it should redirect him to Facebook login view. But after integrating Auth0 it first takes me to the Auth0's login page and then on clicking on Facebook it redirects to the Facebook page.

Is there a way I can integrate the default Facebook Login here without using the Auth0 UI?

Answer (score 1):

```
 func getUserDeatils()
    {
        let loginManager:FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager.init();
        loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email", "public_profile", "user_friends"], fromViewController: nil, handler: {(loginResult, error) -> Void in

            FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters:["fields":"email,first_name, last_name, name"], HTTPMethod: "GET").startWithCompletionHandler {( connection, userResult, error) -> Void in

                if(error == nil)
                {
                    print(userResult);
                }
                else
                {
                    print(error.description);
                }

                loginManager.logOut();
            };

        })
    }
```

and you need to follow the facebook integration process from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started

Comment: Thanks, But the client wants the Facebook integration using Auth0. If you know anything about it please tell me.

Comment: abhijeet-mallick- I want that when the user clicks the Facebook button in my app it should redirect him to Facebook login view your requirement is this right??